# how to send data to js from html

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to send the data with `data-=""` to JavaScript so I using data-= like this in html

```js
const detailInput = document.getElementsByClassName('avg');
const d = 0,
  c = 0,
  b = 0,
  a = 0;

for (let input of detailInput) {
  d = input.datasets.pentingd
  c = input.datasets.pentingc
  b = input.datasets.pentingb
  a = input.datasets.pentinga
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="avg" data-avgpentingd="<?php $avgPuas ?>">
```

but it cannot be because it says `undefined is not an object`. is there any solution please

Comment: are you meaning to use `dataset` and not `datasets`?

Comment: it's `dataset` NOT `datasets`

Comment: You can't redefine a constant

Comment: oh that's why @VilleKoo

Comment: It not error and I change const to var but I think still no data. is there a way to see js data?

Comment: avgpentingd != pentingd

Comment: The attribute is `data-avgpentingd` but you refer to `input.datasets.pentingd`. If you fix it, it should work: https://jsbin.com/wevasod/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Click the edit button and correct the typo to not get downvotes and come back and tell us when you have a solution to get upvotes (but then the post is probably forgotten)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `let` instead of `const` to assign a variable, otherwise it is a constant that can not be changed.
- It is `dataset`, not *datasets*
- You have the name *avgpentingd* but have missed to change *pentingd*
- Maybe use the english word [*pending*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pending) instead of *penting*?
- Open the console in your browser and follow the errors. In Firefox or Chrome click the menu in upper right corner and select the tools for developers and web console. This is a must if you not have another debuger.

After the corrections and minimal change of your code it looks like this and works:

```js
const detailInput = document.getElementsByClassName('avg');
let d = 0,
  c = 0,
  b = 0,
  a = 0;

for (let input of detailInput) {
  d = input.dataset.avgpentingd
  c = input.dataset.avgpentingc
  b = input.dataset.avgpentingb
  a = input.dataset.avgpentinga
}

console.log(d);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="avg" data-avgpentingd="It works now">
```

Read about dataset [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in your javascript:

```
const detailInput = document.getElementsByClassName('avg');

let pentings = array();

for (let input in detailInput) {
  pentings.push(input.dataset.penting);
}

console.table(pentings);
```

In your HTML do this:

```html
<input type="hidden" class="avg" data-penting="<?php $avgPuas ?>">
```

You can also add multiple `input` tags here

Comment: Then see the console in the Chrome's developer tools window